# V4 printer driver architecture for windows 8

Tags: printing, windows-8, driver

windows 8 has introduced a new printer driver architecture known as V4. what are the major changes over previous printer driver architecture?

Comment: This sort of question would be best answered by the official Microsoft documentation on the topic.

Comment: my bad here.. but i want to provide a short summary about the architecture here...

Answer (score 2):

The driver's design philosophy is aligned With the Metro style apps experience and windows store. here are few changes:

1. V4 drivers are also XPS filter pipleline based, so no core changes as such.
2. UI Plug-in support has been removed. so the UI will be traditional PPD/ GPD based, otherwise OEMs will have to develop a metro application to run in metro mode and separate desktop application to provide custom UI.
3. a GUID will be assigned to every driver so that metro style apps and their updates can be installed from the windows store on the basis of the driver GUID.
4. Enhanced Point and print support has been added. with this the driver will never be downloaded on windows versions prior to windows8, but the printing will be enabled using the default point and print driver.

whitepaper on developing v4 printer drivers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/br259124.aspx